# Can we use dot commands(Special Commands of SQlite) in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
string batFilePath = @"D:\mockforbat.bat";
if (!File.Exists(batFilePath))
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(batFilePath))
    {
        fs.Close();
    }
}

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(batFilePath))
{
    sw.WriteLine(@".mode csv");
    sw.WriteLine(@".import D:/Ashif/SQLITE/Bulk.csv excelUpload");
}


SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn);

cmd.CommandText = ".read D:/mockforbar.bat";
SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

As i execute this command i am getting this error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll
>
> Additional information: SQL logic error
>
> near ".": syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use [the Sqlite command-line commands](https://sqlite.org/cli.html) (like `.read` and `.import`) using `SQLiteCommand`.

You'll need to invoke the command-line `sqlite` or `sqlite3` programs using `System.Diagnostics.Process` to run those commands.